# Can I identify when a file was uploaded to a website?

Tags: java, html, file, date, upload

i'm trying to identify when a pdf was uploaded to a website.  my first time checking headers, i see it has a Last Modified date.
the website is for my condominium association.  it has one page that just have links to different pdf files.  It lists the name and then a link to open the pdf.

when i am checking headers, under Network, it shows the name documents representing the page that i am on that contains all these pdfs (.com/community_portal/documents), but it doesnt list out the name of each of these pdf's; which i would want so i can check when each of those was uploaded to the website

went through all the related questions on this site.  i'm not too familiar with code, so this is new to me...

Comment: “…checking headers, i see it has a Last Modified date.” That seems like the answer to me.  There’s even a [URLConnection.getLastModified()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getLastModified%28%29) convenience method for reading it.